# Determining the results of a trailing stoploss for every row using Python Pandas vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am wondering if the following can be achieved using Pandas vectorization, and if so what the code would be. I believe the code would be fairly straightforward if I were to use iterrows, but that would take too long to execute for dataframe.

I have a Python dataframe that contains open-high-low-close (OHLC) chart data for a stock. It also has an additional column, ATR.

```
                 Open       High        Low      Close       ATR
Date                                                            
2010-02-11  31.250000  31.440001  30.719999  31.209999  1.126428
2010-02-12  30.760000  31.010000  30.510000  30.850000  1.121429
2010-02-16  31.450001  31.590000  31.120001  31.549999  1.100000
2010-02-17  31.600000  31.910000  31.360001  31.459999  1.086429
2010-02-18  31.490000  31.770000  31.309999  31.680000  1.018572
...               ...        ...        ...        ...       ...
2020-12-22  21.670000  21.809999  21.100000  21.219999  0.910000
2020-12-23  21.340000  22.219999  21.340000  22.080000  0.924285
2020-12-24  22.100000  22.160000  21.650000  21.889999  0.842857
2020-12-29  21.990000  22.230000  21.590000  21.590000  0.835000
2020-12-30  21.590000  22.180000  21.549999  21.760000  0.817857

[2731 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to generate two new columns for the dataframe: "Exit Date" and "Exit Price". For each row, the value of these columns to be determined as follows:

- If the stock was bought at the Open price of that row, then the Exit Date will be equal to the index of the next row at which the Low price is lower than the trailing stop loss.
- The trailing stop loss in this case will be defined as Low price minus ATR. If this value is lower than the previous row's, then it equals the previous row's value. Due to this, there isn't a single series of values that make up the trailing stop loss for the entire dataframe. The trailing stop loss will vary for each row of the dataframe. An example of this is illustrated in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iabF.png). In this example, Buying on days 1,2,3 and 4 will result in the same trailing stop loss. However, buying on day 8 results in a different trailing stop loss.
- The Exit Price will be equal to the Open price of the Exit Date if it is lower than the stop loss. Otherwise the Exit Price will be equal to the stop loss.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([("2010-02-11", 31.250000, 31.440001, 30.719999, 31.209999, 1.126428),
    ("2010-02-12", 30.760000, 31.010000, 30.510000, 30.850000, 1.121429),
    ("2010-02-16", 31.450001, 31.590000, 31.120001, 31.549999, 1.100000),
    ("2010-02-17", 31.600000, 31.910000, 31.360001, 31.459999, 1.086429),
    ("2010-02-18", 31.490000, 31.770000, 31.309999, 31.680000, 1.018572),
    ("2020-12-22", 21.670000, 21.809999, 21.100000, 21.219999, 0.910000),
    ("2020-12-23", 21.340000, 22.219999, 21.340000, 22.080000, 0.924285),
    ("2020-12-24", 22.100000, 22.160000, 21.650000, 21.889999, 0.842857),
    ("2020-12-29", 21.990000, 22.230000, 21.590000, 21.590000, 0.835000),
    ("2020-12-30", 21.590000, 22.180000, 21.549999, 21.760000, 0.817857)], 
    columns = ['Index', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'ATR'])

df.set_index('Index', inplace=True)    

def get_row_trailing_out_dates_and_prices(data: pd.DataFrame, pct=0.02, referenced='Low') -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Marca a cada fila con su fecha de salida y el precio de salida"""
    df = data.copy(deep=True)
    df['Low_ATR'] = df['Low'] - df['ATR']
    results = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        curr_df = df.loc[idx:, :].copy()
        curr_df['Trailing_Stop'] = curr_df[referenced].cummax() * (1 - pct)
        curr_df['Exit_Signal'] = curr_df['Low'] < curr_df['Trailing_Stop']
        this_row = curr_df.index[0]
        try:
            exit_date = curr_df.loc[curr_df['Exit_Signal']].index[0]
            exit_price = curr_df.loc[exit_date]['Trailing_Stop']
        except IndexError:
            exit_date = np.nan
            exit_price = np.nan
        new_row = [this_row, exit_date, exit_price]
        results.append(new_row)
    return pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Index', 'Exit Date', 'Exit Price']).set_index('Index')
```

And the results are:

```
get_row_trailing_out(df)

                 Exit Date  Exit Price
Index                             
2010-02-11  2020-12-22   30.732801
2010-02-12  2020-12-22   30.732801
2010-02-16  2020-12-22   30.732801
2010-02-17  2020-12-22   30.732801
2010-02-18  2020-12-22   30.683799
2020-12-22         NaN         NaN
2020-12-23         NaN         NaN
2020-12-24         NaN         NaN
2020-12-29         NaN         NaN
2020-12-30         NaN         NaN
```

Changing the percentaje of trailing stop loss:

```
get_row_trailing_out(df, pct=0.005)

             Exit Date  Exit Price
Index                             
2010-02-11  2010-02-12   30.566399
2010-02-12  2020-12-22   31.203201
2010-02-16  2020-12-22   31.203201
2010-02-17  2020-12-22   31.203201
2010-02-18  2020-12-22   31.153449
2020-12-22         NaN         NaN
2020-12-23         NaN         NaN
2020-12-24         NaN         NaN
2020-12-29         NaN         NaN
2020-12-30         NaN         NaN
```